# Unreal Engine 4: Accessing Custom Parent Blueprint's Components

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a problem in reparenting blueprints. I've created a blueprint called "BP_Collectible". It has 3 components; Audio, StaticMesh and a box collider. If an actor touches this blueprint (box collider), audio is playing immediately and destroying the object. Everything fine.

Now I am trying to create two blueprints called "BP_Coin" and "BP_Heart" which are children of "BP_Collectible". The three components of BP_Collectible is visible on these blueprints but I cannot change mesh of the StaticMesh and AudioClip of Audio either. I want to make two different collectible, which must have BP_Collectible behaviour but have different mesh and audio.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

There was an example what I exactly needed project in Content Examples.

The solution is creating variables for them. In inherited blueprints, these variables can be changed in Defaults section.